# How can I have people log into my network and be directed to my website?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

So what I am trying to accomplish is somewhat like Starbucks has, were you connect to there wifi, accept terms, then it directs them to there website. Can this be accomplished with a mobile hotspot?  Another thing is that when they try to go to another site it will be locked into my site, so while logged into my wifi they will only be allowed to access our website. Is this possible?

I am a mobile DJ that would like guest at any event to be able to access our site through there mobile and send the DJ a direct song request.

Answer (score 0):

This method to access a wifi network is called a captive portal. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal for a list of software to implement this.

Comment: Can this be achieved with a mobile hotspot?

Comment: A mobile or fixed hotspot is the same as long as you can carry the required equipment to run the software you need to achieve what you want. The required equipment will depend on the solution you choose to implement your captive portal. I guess in addition to a wireless AP you may need a server to run the authentication, portal software, etc. A laptop would be better suited if you wish to be mobile. Have a look at Tomato (http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) and dd-wrt (http://www.dd-wrt.ca/site/index) I would not be surprised they support captive portal out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [WiFIDog](http://dev.wifidog.org/) solution, it's open source and can be configured in details. It has three main functions:

Location-aware delivery of internal or external content

Authentication and authorization

Centralizaed network monitoring